# A self selecting team

Tags: algorithm, combinations, genetic-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

A team consisting of 100 members is to be assembled from a pool of 1000 applicants.
Each applicant gets to pick the 99 other applicants he/she would like to have as teammates.

Each possible team gets a score that measures how well it satisfies the team mate preferences of its members. If Lisa is in a team and 11 of the people on Lisas wishlist are also in the team that team gets 11 points for Lisa. The points for all members are added up. The theoretical maximum any possible team can get is 99*100. The minimum is 0.

Now we want to find the team with the highest score. Trying to brute force this problem by computing the score for each possible combination (≈ 10^140) is not an option.

Is there a clever algorithm that will take a shortcut to the best answer or will one have to settle for an algorithm that finds a good answer?

Comment: An interesting question.  I feel certain that there are ways to improve the brute-force search for the deterministic solution over C(1000,100), but I suspect that they are at best geometric improvements.  For a tractable solution, I think that you'll have to resort to heuristics.

Comment: Looks like an eigenvalue problem to me. Google for "power iteration"

Comment: This client project has now launched. [Curatron Equation](http://curatroneq.com) is Saas platform for crowdsourcing the artistic curatorial process.

Comment: And I ended up doing a simple genetic algorithm that I jumpstart with pairs or triplets of applicants that have a high "team mate preference" score.

Answer (score 5):

I think that if you could solve this efficiently you could solve the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem efficiently - where there is a link between two nodes put each node on the list of the nodes that the other wants to work with. Looking at the article, I think you will find it hard to find even a guaranteed good approximation, unless your problem has some special structure to it.

Comment: Good catch.  I agree, this very much looks like a substantial super-set of the Clique problem.  Given that the Clique problem is *very* intractable, we can probably be fairly sure that this problem is too (or much likely, even harder).  So, very unlikely to have a tractable deterministic solution.

Answer (score 2):

You might try a [hill climbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing_algorithm) algorithm. Start with a member who is "popular" (picked most often by other members), and incrementally add new members who increase the team score the most. This is unfortunately not guaranteed to find the best solution, but it will probably find good ones. To improve your solution you could try [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing).

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, the score is calculated as 99 (from the person picking his team - since they must all be on his list) + the sum of the other 99 team members count of the applicants on their wish list that are on the team.

You already know the theoretical maximum team score, so I don't understand why you would need to go through all the combinations.  Iterating through all 1000 teams to find the best score should be relatively trivial.  1000 teams * 100 members per team is easily solvable.

Comment: Bob: There are way more than 1000 teams. There are 1000!/900! teams (1000 ways of picking team member #1, 999 ways of picking team member #2, etc.)